# CKEditor change names and tags in Formatting drop down

Tags: drop-down-menu, formatting, ckeditor

Where from can I edit the names and tags inserted when selecting an option from the Formatting drop-down in CKEDitor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you can set these with the config option 'format_tags', like so:
`config.format_tags = 'p;pre;h1;h2';`

However, a bug exists in drupal's ckeditor.module, where this setting is being overwritten. Go to the /admin/settings/ckeditor folder in your drupal install and edit the settings there.

Comment: Yes, but how do you add a new format, such as `<aside>`? (The source code documentation makes it look like you can simply add it as you mentioned, and then specify the format elsewhere in the config, but you also somehow have to update the localization file, and I've seen no examples of this.)

Comment: @GarretWilson See http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.format_tags

You have to add `config.format_aside = ...` and I believe add something to some language files, though I'm still working on that myself!

Comment: @jezmck Um, yes, but the link you gave only mentions tags known by the plugin. The question I raised was about how to add a new format such as `<aside>`.

Comment: @jezmk Yes, I tried it. It didn't work for me. And if it worked for you, why did you say, "...and I believe add something to some language files, though I'm still working on that myself"? What did it show for you in the pulldown menu?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `replace` method, your code can look like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace(element, {
    format_small: {element: 'small', name: 'Small'},
    format_tags: 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;div;small'
}) ;
```

I couldn't find any documentation on the "name" parameter and just guessed it.

Comment: format_(tag) doesn't accept a `name` key, except for undefined non-default elements. For example, this will work for `<small>` but not for `<p>`

Comment: A hack around this is to create a custom format name like this:
'format_my_custom_name' : {'element': 'h6', 'name': 'My Custom Name'},`
then include it on your format tags list: `'format_tags': 'p;h3;h4;h5;pre;format_my_custom_name',`